# Regular Express to keep the last number within the bracket

Tags: regex

I copied this from Wiki source code

```
[[1970–71 NFL playoffs|1970]], [[1971–72 NFL playoffs|1971]], [[1972–73 NFL playoffs|1972]], [[1973–74 NFL playoffs|1973]], [[1974–75 NFL playoffs|1974]], [[1978–79 NFL playoffs|1978]], [[1979–80 NFL playoffs|1979]], [[1981–82 NFL playoffs|1981]], [[1982–83 NFL playoffs|1982]], [[1983–84 NFL playoffs|1983]], [[1984–85 NFL playoffs|1984]], [[1985–86 NFL playoffs|1985]], [[1990–91 NFL playoffs|1990]], [[1992–93 NFL playoffs|1992]], [[1994–95 NFL playoffs|1994]], [[1995–96 NFL playoffs|1995]], [[1997–98 NFL playoffs|1997]], [[1998–99 NFL playoffs|1998]], [[1999–2000 NFL playoffs|1999]], [[2000–01 NFL playoffs|2000]], [[2001–02 NFL playoffs|2001]], [[2008–09 NFL playoffs|2008]], [[2016–17 NFL playoffs|2016]]
```

And I would like to replace it into

```
1970，1971，...
```

I'd like to replace

- comma, following by space (, ) with another comma (，)
- `[[XXXX|YYYY]]` into `YYYY` (I would prefer more generic)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try the following find and replace, in regex mode:

```
Find:    \[\[\d+–\d+ NFL playoffs\|(\d{4})\]\]
Replace: $1
```

### Demo

Comment: Thanks... Just wonder if it is possible to replace the comma with another comma (within the same regex)? Thanks again

Comment: Also, I tried to remove the 'NFL playoffs' word but it doesn't work. Just wonder if it is possible to obtain a more generic regex that replace '[[XXXXX|YYYY]]' into 'YYYY'? Thanks

Comment: @Winston For your first comment, [see the updated demo here](https://regex101.com/r/vxIdgs/2).  For the second comment, that's _not_ what you asked, and I'm not going to update my answer.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Yeah I think I asked too specific. So wonder if a more generic solution is possible.

Comment: Maybe this pattern? `\[\[\d+–\d+ .*?\|(\d{4})\]\]` .. this would just require the year information, but the text before the pipe could literally be anything?  It's hard for me to guess, because the pattern I gave you does actually work for the data you provided.

Comment: I would personally prefer `\[\[.*?\|(.*?)\]\](?:(,) )?`. Still, thanks for the help

Comment: For future reference, I suggest always showing us the real data, covering all edge cases.  Otherwise, you get an answer which might fit the sample data, but won't work on the actual data.